# Exec format error when trying to run scripts from eshell

Tags: eshell

i get the following error no matter which simple bash script i try to run

`emacs: /home/zeltak/bin/zbak.sh: Exec format error`

all the scripts work great from bash/zsh

is this a known issue? cant you run bash scripts from eshell?

Comment: Starting bash scripts works fine in my Emacs shell. Even without the #!/bin/bash line. Have you tried "bash script.sh"?

Comment: yeah that worked! so is there someway to make eshel know this or do i need to add the bash statment each time i want to run a bash script?